# How to categorize data?

Tags: python

I am trying to create a code that will ask the user to input different points and it will randomly select points and calculate the distance between them. What I want to do is constantly select a random point from a group, calculate the distance, and re-group the data based on what point it was closest to. I have gotten to a point in my code where I can't figure out how to categorize the data without changing its value. If anyone has any suggestions on how to improve my code and/or solve my problem, they would be greatly appreciated.

```
from random import*
import math

d = 0
c = 0
points = []
values = []
groups = int(input("How many groups of data: "))

data = int(input("How many data points would you like to enter: "))
for i in range(data):
    values = []
    x = values.append(int(input("X-value:")))
    y = values.append(int(input("Y-value:")))
    points.append(values)

a = sample(range(data), groups)
res = [int(item) for item in a]

for f in range(groups):
    for g in range(data):
        b = points[a[c]]
        e = points[d]
        d = -1
        for h in range(data-groups):
            if e==b:
                d=d+1
                e = points[d]
            else:
                d=d+1
                e = points[d]
            dist = math.sqrt((b[0]-e[0])**2+(b[1]-e[1])**2)
        
    c = c + 1
```